# how to make a div that looks like this button in CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, web

I am trying to create a div that will have following look alike CSS.

Though i am not sure how to get that kind of texture with just CSS also how to add multiple borders like this one( there dark border around white border and internal content has little bit of gradiant shadowy looks.

```
Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ad4xv9mt/11/
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ad4xv9mt/11/)

[image]

Edit: adding a clear image

[image]

Comment: you picture is hard to see ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif just added another clear image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the border you can use multiple box-shadow, and for the background you can use linear/radial-gradient to have something similar to the image:

```css
.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  background:
  radial-gradient(circle at center, #984675 20%,purple )0 0/10px 10px ;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px #fff solid;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000,
  2px 2px 1px red,
  -2px -2px 1px red,
  -2px 2px 1px red,
  2px -2px 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <div class="box1">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is one of high complexity: it contains alternate sinusoidal lines delimiting mirrored drop-like areas, each filled by an offset circular background gradient to create the the illusion of 3d rounded bumps illuminated slightly from top.

To recreate this pattern using any tools (Adobe products or similar) takes advanced skill levels, especially if the result has to be a vector (loss-less scalable image quality). Asking for programming such a vector image pattern is clearly *off-topic* on SO, for at least three reasons:

- not a programming question, as defined in help center,
- you haven't made an attempt at coding it yourself,
- it's too broad (too much work required)

---

The sane alternative is to find the smallest repeatable crop of the image without any shadow applied and use `background-repeat` property. On top of that, apply shadow as suggested in Temani's answer.
A valuable resource when it comes to "natural" `box-shadow` effects is AngularJS Material Design's [Whiteframe](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/whiteframe) (you'll need to use your browser's dev tools and inspect the elements).

As far as CSS goes, you'll need

```
background-image: url('link-to-image');
background-repeat: repeat;
```

...applied to your button to repeat the image as background. See [this post](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-repeat/) for more `background` tricks.